# Angular 6 - Date pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, date-pipe

could some one tell how to achieve below format in angular?.

expected:

> 20JAN2019

right now with angular default pipe. am getting like

> 20/01/2019
>   when using {{slotEndDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

do i need write custom pipe to get desired output?

kindly share some examples or demo stackblitz.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built in `DatePipe` of Angular. See the available formatting options [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

To format the date to your liking you would need to use `ddMMMyyyy`.